# How to make a non-template global function that works on a template class?

Tags: c++, class, templates

The question is probably unclear so let me explain on an example. I have a template class `PairContainer<T1, T2>` with a public function:

```
//somewhere in PairContainer class definition
void foo(PairContainer& pc)
{
    //do something
}
```

Now I want to make a function `bar` that can be called like this:

```
//somewhere in main...
PairContainer<int, int> pc1;
PairContainer<some_class, some_other_class> pc2;
bar(pc1, pc2); //is equivalent to pc1.foo(pc2)
```

How can I do that? I can't do:

```
void bar(PairContainer& pc1, PairContainer& pc2)
{
    pc1.foo(pc2);
}
```

since this won't compile ("missing template arguments").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accept a `PairContainer` with any template arguments in `foo`, then it needs to be a template function with template parameters for the `pc` argument:

```
template <typename Y1, typename Y2>
void foo (PairContainer<Y1, Y2>& pc) 
{

}
```

Then `bar` needs to be a template function with template parameters for both `PairContainer`s:

```
template <typename X1, typename X2, typename Y1, typename Y2>
void bar(PairContainer<X1,X2>& pc1, PairContainer<Y1,Y2>& pc2)
{
    pc1.foo(pc2);
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that `bar` will have to be called as `bar<int, int, some_class, some_other_class>(pc1, pc2)`?

Comment: No, `bar(pc1, pc2)` will do, the template arguments can be deduced.

Comment: Huh, I didn't expect that. Then this solves my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`PairContainer` is not a type. It is a template. It means, it can not be used where types are expected, in particular, in function definition. You can create a function bar which accepts **specific** instance of PairContainer template, like this:

```
void bar(PairContainer<int, int>, PairContainer<some_class, some_other_class>)
```

but I doubt this is what you want.

The only way to make `bar` accepting any type of `PairContainer` is by making it a template.

By the way, the reason why you can have a construct like `void foo(PairContainer& pc)`inside your class definition is because `PairContainer` is a short-hand and just means `PairContainer<T1, T2>`

Comment: Thanks for the "by the way" part, never thought of it this way

Comment: @Dunno, just to clarify my note, since I found it might be worded amibiguosly - what I meant was that inside template class defintion, class name without template arguments means 'class type as instantiated'.

Answer (score 1):

You are either going to have to specify the types of `PairContainer`s you want to take or use templates.

You could make both sides of the function a different template type

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void bar(T& pc1, U& pc2)
{
    pc1.foo(pc2);
}
```

But this will work for any two types.  To limit it to just two different `PairContainer`s then you can use

```
template<typename Ty, typename Tu, typename Uy, typename Uu>
void bar(PairContainer<Ty, Tu>& pc1, PairContainer<Uy, Uu>& pc2)
{
    pc1.foo(pc2);
}
```